# John the Baptist appeared to Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery as a resurrected being. When was John the Baptist resurrected?

Tags: lds

According to [this article](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/friend/1995/04/john-the-baptist?lang=eng) on lds.org, LDS believe John the Baptist appeared to Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery as angel/resurrected being:

> When Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery were translating the Book of
> Mormon, they came across a passage concerning baptism. On May 15,
> 1829, they went into the woods to pray to understand this principle.
> In answer to their prayers, the resurrected John the Baptist appeared
> to them. He laid his hands upon their heads and ordained them to the
> Aaronic Priesthood,[...]

If John the Baptist did indeed appear to Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery as a resurrected being, when was he resurrected?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mark. If you take the tour you will be helped to see how this site differs from others (bottom l.h.s. of this page). One point is that some research needs to be shown as to why you ask the Q. It's insufficient to make a bald claim with no supporting points/links, especially when this particular claim is only believed in LDS circles. The Q needs to have 'Allegedly' at the start.

Comment: @Anne better like this?

Answer (score 4):

Some time between Jesus resurrection and the appearance as angel.

The First Resurrection is not starting after the Second Coming, it has already started with Christs resurrection, and is ongoing.

Matthew 27:52-53

> 52 And the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which
> slept arose,
>
> 53 And came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into
> the holy city, and appeared unto many.

Mosiah 15:21-22

> 21 And there cometh a resurrection, even a first resurrection; yea,
> even a resurrection of those that have been, and who are, and who
> shall be, even until the resurrection of Christ—for so shall he be
> called.
>
> 22 And now, the resurrection of all the prophets, and all those that
> have believed in their words, or all those that have kept the
> commandments of God, shall come forth in the first resurrection;
> therefore, they are the first resurrection.

D&C 138:50-52

> 50 For the dead had looked upon the long absence of their spirits
> from their bodies as a bondage.
>
> 51 These the Lord taught, and gave them power to come forth, after
> his resurrection from the dead, to enter into his Father’s kingdom,
> there to be crowned with immortality and eternal life,
>
> 52 And continue thenceforth their labor as had been promised by the
> Lord, and be partakers of all blessings which were held in reserve
> for them that love him.